# GSON deserializing generic type

Tags: java, generics, deserialization, gson

I have following class which is basically response from web service.

```
public class WSGenericMessage<T> implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Boolean ResponseCode;
private String ResponseMessage;
private Class<T> ResponseData;

public Boolean getResponseCode() {
    return ResponseCode;
}

public void setResponseCode(Boolean responseCode) {
    ResponseCode = responseCode;
}

public String getResponseMessage() {
    return ResponseMessage;
}

public void setResponseMessage(String responseMessage) {
    ResponseMessage = responseMessage;
}

public Class<T> getResponseData() {
    return ResponseData;
}

public void setResponseData(Class<T> responseData) {
    ResponseData = responseData;
}

}
```

Is it possible to deserialize json string in following way:

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Type type = new TypeToken<WSGenericMessage<String>>(){}.getType();
  gson.fromJson(result, type);
```

I am getting:

```
   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something like **type erasure**, so generic types are erased and not available in runtime.

So you can deserialize object giving class without generic classifiers, and than 'cast' to proper type.

But you problem is not the generic types deserialization, but the type that contains `java.lang.Class` object. This can't be serialized and deserialized.

For serialization and deserialization you should use objects without Class field, use String field with class name, or mark this field as `transient` and restore it afterwards.

Comment: "This can't be serialized and deserialized" - Why not? `Class` implements `Serializable`. Please clarify your answer.

Comment: Right, and I can guess why. I'm just asking you to clarify the reason beyond just "type erasure" for the OP. It would be nice to make sense of the exception message.